# angular acsess 'this' in callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm storing an object inside of the service in my angular app, I can't access 'this' from within the callback method. Something like this...

```
    app.service("myService", ['$http', '$q', 
        function($http, $q) {
            return ({foo: foo});

            this.myObj = {};

          function doSomething(param, callback){
            param++;
            callback(param);
          } 

          function foo(param){
          doSomething(param, function(responce){ 
            this.myObj.myParam = responce;//'this' is undefined
          });
          }
     });
```

How do I access it correctly?
Thank you...

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Will try better next time... Yes, Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `obj` is the object you want to be the this, you can use `bind` to set it as the actual `this` for the function `f`, as an example: `f.bind(obj)`.

As from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value [...]

Answer (score 1):

'this' is only kept in current scope of the function. when called inside a new function 'this' changes. what most people do is var that = this;

```
 app.service("myService", ['$http', '$q', 
    function($http, $q) {
        var that = this;

        return ({foo: foo});

        this.myObj = {};

      function doSomething(param, callback){
        param++;
        callback(param);
      } 

      function foo(param){
        doSomething(param, function(responce){ 
          that.myObj.myParam = responce;//'that' defined
        });
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store first "this" object into some variable.
And you should use it inside callback function.

```
app.service("myService", ['$http', '$q', 
    function($http, $q) {
        return ({foo: foo});
        var self = this;
        self.myObj = {};

      function doSomething(param, callback){
        param++;
        callback(param);
      } 

      function foo(param){
      doSomething(param, function(responce){ 
        self.myObj.myParam = responce;
      });
      }
 });
```

I wish it helped you.